# Need to remove permission level from a SharePoint group using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I was able to create a PowerShell script that creates a new permission level and assigns it to a group. However, I noticed that it doesn't replace the previous permission level of that group. So how can I create a script that removes the additional permission level of that group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [a script on the MSDN SharePoint forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/6773d68c-415a-442b-9fef-ce1220af55e9) that seems to have the answer.  What I get from looking at the script is that it seems you have to remove the role definition for that permission level from the role definition bindings on the role assignments for the group.  (Say that three times fast! ;)

Directly pulled from the link above:

```
function Remove-SPGroupPermission([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroup]$group, [string[]]$permissions) {
  $ra = $group.ParentWeb.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal($group)
  foreach ($permission in $permissions) {
    $rd = $group.ParentWeb.RoleDefinitions[$permission]
    $ra.RoleDefinitionBindings.Remove($rd)
  }
  $ra.Update()
  $group.Update()
}
```

EDIT:

Ok, so what you want would probably look something like this, in a very simple form:

```
$web = get-spweb http://url/to/your/web
$group = $web.SiteGroups["Owners"]
$ra = $group.ParentWeb.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal($group)
$rd = $group.ParentWeb.RoleDefinitions["Full Control"]
$ra.RoleDefinitionBindings.Remove($rd)
$ra.Update()
$group.Update()
$web.Dispose()
```

Or, if you wanted to use the function posted above, something like this:

```
function Remove-SPGroupPermission([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroup]$group, [string[]]$permissions) {
  $ra = $group.ParentWeb.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal($group)
  foreach ($permission in $permissions) {
    $rd = $group.ParentWeb.RoleDefinitions[$permission]
    $ra.RoleDefinitionBindings.Remove($rd)
  }
  $ra.Update()
  $group.Update()
}

$web = get-spweb http://url/to/your/web
$group = $web.SiteGroups["Owners"]
$permissionsToRemove = @("Full Control")

Remove-SPGroupPermission -group $group -permissions $permissionsToRemove

$web.Dispose()
```

Comment: The above script will remove all permissions the group has. You'd then need to re-add any that you'd need.

Comment: Well... won't it just remove all the permissions listed in the [string[]]$permissions parameter?  And if that parameter happens to be an array of just one element, then it would only remove the one permission?

Comment: Whoops, you're right. I completely missed that $permissions was a parameter of the function.

Comment: Well, I'm having trouble getting it to work. Where in the script should I place the permission "Full Control" that I'm trying to remove and where would I place the group "Owners". How should it look like?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you what it should look like for your specific case.

Comment: When I try the simple form I get the following error "Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb] doesn't contain a method named 'SiteGroups'. I'm a PowerShell newbie so I don't have any idea what this means. @DylanCristy

Comment: Oh, my bad, those should have square brackets, not parentheses.  Corrected in the answer.

Comment: Yeah, that did the trick. Thank you so much, such a little simple thing can be such a pain. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint Online refer to: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161387.aspx

```
Set-SPOSiteGroup -Site http://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/siteA -Identity "ProjectViewers" -PermissionLevelsToRemove "Full Control" -PermissionLevelsToAdd "View Only"
```

> Example 1 changes permission level of the ProjectViewers group inside
>   site collection http://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/siteA from Full
>   Control to View Only.