# Remove a permission level for a group that's assigned to the folder through PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, item-level-permissions, custom-permission-level

I got the  code for removing permission at the `web` level, but how can I implement the same for all of my `folders` within my doc `lib`?
here its the code for removing permissions for a group at web level :
[HERE_ITS](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70071/need-to-remove-permission-level-from-a-sharepoint-group-using-powershell)

```
$web = get-spweb http://url/to/your/web
$group = $web.SiteGroups["Owners"]
$ra = $group.ParentWeb.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal($group)
$rd = $group.ParentWeb.RoleDefinitions["Full Control"]
$ra.RoleDefinitionBindings.Remove($rd)
$ra.Update()
$group.Update()
$web.Dispose()
```

Already I have broken all the `folder` level permissions and added one additional permissions, like `contributenodelete` or `customdesignPermLevel`.

Now I wanna remove this `CustomDesignPermLevel` alone without touching the `controbutenodlete` for all the `folders`.

How can I achieve this using PowerShell?